Using Dynamic Namespaces in NestJs Gateways
I am implementing a multi-tenancy chat app and want each tenant to connect to their own namespace. Native socket-io has this feature but it seems that NestJs gateways doesn't have this feature.
I have search the docs and googled but couldn't find anything.
Any pointers how to use dynamic namespaces in NestJs Gateways would be appreciated.
If it is not possible to use dynamic namespaces in NestJs Gateways and i have to use native socket-io namespaces how do i go about implementing socket-io server in NestJs provider without gateways?
